# InfoPath Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, calculated-column

I have implemented a little calculated field in my infopath form that calculates it's value from another field. The field it is calculating it's value from was already filled out before I added the the calculated field. With that said, why isn't this new field calculating it's value now? I have to manually go in to change for it to update?

I feel there is a better way to do this....

Comment: Are you having SharePoint do the calculating or InfoPath?

Comment: I am having InfoPath do the calculation.

Comment: Check to see if the calculated field is set to refresh automatically, or you might need to put a rule on your trigger field to recalculate the calculated field on change.

Comment: Refresh automatically? Would this be in InfoPath or SharePoint? I see a refresh automatically in InfoPath below default value but it's grey and I cannot check.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a rule to do the calculation for you on field change and have it set the "calculated field" for you. I do not know what kind of calculation you are doing, sorry could be of more help.